# Move rows from Table1 to Table2 (archive) and just keep past 7 days of data in Table1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, move, archive

Table1 has columns including created date. I want to archive rows older than the past 7 days for which I would like to move those into a new table, Table2.
How do I script which will update the archive data into Table 2 and just retain data only for the past 7 days in Table1. Thanks!

Comment: Your code? Where are you stucked?

Comment: INSERT INTO Table2 (columns.....) Select (columns...) from Table2 where createddate >= DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())                                                   DELETE from Table1 where createddate >= DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to do something like this:

```
declare @cutoff_datetime datetime;
set @cutoff_datetime = dateadd(day, -7, getdate());

insert into table2 ( . . . )
    select . . .
    from table1
    where createdate < @cutoff_datetime;

delete from table1
    where createdate < @cutoff_datetime;
```

This is transaction safe under the following two circumstances:

- Rows are not updated in `table1`; and,
- New rows are inserted with the current time.

If rows can be updated, you should ask *another* question with much more detailed specifications about what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon..it didn't work as expected. I have rows created from May 3rd till date. When I ran the script as suggested with -4 instead of -7. it gives me the following results:                                                                                                           Table 1 still has some rows created on May 3rd                                             Table 2 has some rows created on May 3, 4 till 8.

Comment: That is because `getdate()` has a time component.  You case use `cast(getdate() as date)` to remove the time component.

Comment: That's fine but when I used -6 instead of -7 it archived and deleted all rows since May 3 when I thought it would just archive and delete all rows created on May 3 and retain rows in the main table (table1) from May 4 till date.

Answer (score 0):

This uses `datadd()` and `datediff()` to get the start of the day 7 days ago, and deletes rows from `table1` earlier than 7 days ago; while using [**`output`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) to insert the deleted rows into `table2`.

```
insert into table2 (col1, col2, some_date)
select d.col1, d.col2, d.some_date
from (
  delete 
  from table1
  output deleted.col1, deleted.col2, deleted.some_date
  where some_date <  dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate() -7), 0)
  ) d (col1, col2, some_date)
```

---

Rextester demo: http://rextester.com/DNK69844

```
create table table1 (col1 int not null identity(2,1), col2 varchar(32), some_date date);
insert into table1 values ('Eight','20170429'),('Seven','20170430'),('Six','20170501');

create table table2 (col1 int not null, col2 varchar(32), some_date date);
insert into table2 values (1,'Nine','20170428');

select tbl='table1', col1, col2, some_date=convert(char(10),some_date,120) from table1
union all
select tbl='table2', col1, col2, some_date=convert(char(10),some_date,120) from table2;

insert into table2 (col1, col2, some_date)
select d.col1, d.col2, d.some_date
from (
  delete 
  from table1
  output deleted.col1, deleted.col2, deleted.some_date
  where some_date <  dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate() -7), 0)
  ) d (col1, col2, some_date);


select tbl='table1', col1, col2, some_date=convert(char(10),some_date,120) from table1
union all
select tbl='table2', col1, col2, some_date=convert(char(10),some_date,120) from table2;
```

returns (before):

```
+--------+------+-------+------------+
|  tbl   | col1 | col2  | some_date  |
+--------+------+-------+------------+
| table1 |    2 | Eight | 2017-04-29 |
| table1 |    3 | Seven | 2017-04-30 |
| table1 |    4 | Six   | 2017-05-01 |
| table2 |    1 | Nine  | 2017-04-28 |
+--------+------+-------+------------+
```

returns (after):

```
+--------+------+-------+------------+
|  tbl   | col1 | col2  | some_date  |
+--------+------+-------+------------+
| table1 |    3 | Seven | 2017-04-30 |
| table1 |    4 | Six   | 2017-05-01 |
| table2 |    1 | Nine  | 2017-04-28 |
| table2 |    2 | Eight | 2017-04-29 |
+--------+------+-------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

-- Create a temp table

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (PK_Col INT);  -- Only to store the Primary Key values of deleted rows.
GO
```

-- Insert the rows into Archive table

```
INSERT INTO Archive.Table (PK_Col , created_date , OtherCols,.....)
OUTPUT inserted.PK_Col INTO #Temp
SELECT PK_Col , created_date , OtherCols,.....
FROM Table1
WHERE created_date < DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()-7), 0)
GO
```

-- Now delete the Archived data

```
DELETE FROM t
FROM Table1 t
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 from #temp t1 WHERE t1.PK_Col = t.PK_Col)
GO
```